# c# CPU and Memory Monitor Console app keeps warning me that mu CPU load is at 100%

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, performancecounter

I'm assuming I have found myself some sort of a nasty bug. 
I have recently tried to create a console application in c# that prints the CPU Load & available memory every second. Whilst this goes on I have made sure that the application only warns about the CPU usage when the CPU Load goes over 80 percent. With a much more serious warning at 100% as you will see.

However, when i run the application it continually warns me that the CPU is at 100%, even though I know it shouldn't be running anywhere near that. I downloaded CPU Burn In to test the app and push the CPU to 100%, However I am 100 percent sure that it has been disabled the whole time.

I will post my code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace CpuandMemoryMonitor
{
class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Entry Point into the Program | Program: CPU & Memory Monitor |By:  
    Andrew.
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #region My performance Counters
        // This will greet the user in the default voice
        SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        synth.Speak("Welcome to the CPU and Memory Monitor");

        // This will pull the current CPU load in percentage.
        PerformanceCounter perfCpuCount = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");

        // This will pull the current available Memory in Megabytes
        PerformanceCounter perfMemCount = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");

        // This will give us system uptime (in Seconds)
        PerformanceCounter perfUptimecount = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time");

        #endregion

        #region Perfromance Counters Program Loop

        //Infinite While Loop.
        while (true)
        {
            // Get the current perforance counter values
            int currentcpupercentage = (int)perfCpuCount.NextValue();
            int currentavailablememory = (int)perfMemCount.NextValue();

            //Print the performance counter values to the console screen
            Console.WriteLine("CPU Load: {0}%", currentcpupercentage);
            Console.WriteLine("Available Memory: {0}MB", currentavailablememory);

            // Speech synthasiser warns user when CPU Load is above 80 percent
            if (currentcpupercentage > 80)
            {
                ///If CPU Load is at 100 % Warn the user in a a female voice!
                if (currentcpupercentage == 100)
                {
                    synth.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female);
                    string cpuLoadVocalMessage = String.Format("Oh dear! You're CPU is about to catch on Fire!");
                    synth.Speak(cpuLoadVocalMessage);
                }

                else 

                //If CPU Load is at 80 % Warn the user in a a male voice!
                {
                    synth.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male);
                    string cpuLoadVocalMessage = String.Format("The Current Cpu Load is {0}", currentcpupercentage);
                    synth.Speak(cpuLoadVocalMessage);
                }

                // Speech synthasiser warns user when memory is less then 1 gigabyte
                if (currentavailablememory < 1024)

                {
                    // If CPU Load is at 100 % Warn the user ina a female voice!

                    string memavailableVocalMessage = string.Format("You currently have {0} gigabytes of memory available", currentavailablememory / 1024);
                    synth.Speak(memavailableVocalMessage);
                }


                //Sleep for 1 second
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

            }

            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you really running C# version 2 *and* version 4?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be using a `while(true)` loop, instead use a timer that pings on regular intervals.

Comment: Speech is very CPU intensive and with a 1 second loop your app is probably chasing its own tail.

Comment: 'Sleep(1000)' called only if cpu usage is more than 80 .. otherwise it is a continuous call. It shouldn't ping regular intervals.

Comment: Move the thread.Sleep(1000) out if the if statement

Comment: I tryed your code at my place, here are the results I have : CPU Load: 0%
Available Memory: 1344MB
CPU Load: 0%
Available Memory: 1344MB
CPU Load: 0%
Available Memory: 1342MB
CPU Load: 0%
Available Memory: 1342MB
CPU Load: 100%
Available Memory: 1342MB
CPU Load: 17,37111%
Available Memory: 1327MB
CPU Load: 100%
Available Memory: 1327MB
CPU Load: 8,8755%
Available Memory: 1322MB
CPU Load: 100%
Available Memory: 1322MB
CPU Load: 8,524552%
Available Memory: 1306MB
CPU Load: 100%
Available Memory: 1306MB
CPU Load: 7,674673%
Available Memory: 1303MB

Comment: So your code actually starts a tight loop, skipping the `Sleep` which will cause the CPU to jump to 100% immediately. If it gets out of that, it jumps back into the tight loop, again causing 100% CPU.

Comment: I just changed your integer to a float. I sometimes have a 100% peak, but it's not always

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop, if you have an infinite loop the computer will run the code continuously. As others have pointed out in the comments, you should use some form of timer in order to only poll at specific intervals. Even better you can use a WMI Event watcher to get called only when the alarm is hit.

Google WMI Events or read things like;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393013(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response!